# Loading Pytorch model doesn't seem to work

Tags: pytorch

I want to load a pretrained model from PyTorch. Specifically, I want to run the SAT-Speaker-with-emotion-grounding (431MB) [model from this repo](https://github.com/optas/artemis). However, I don't seem to be able to load it. When I download the model and run the script below, I get a dictionary and not the model.

Loading the model:

```
model_emo = torch_load_model('best_model.pt', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
```

Running the model

```
model_emo(image)
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e80ccbe8b6ed> in <module>
----> 1 model_emo(image)

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Now, the docs say that I should instantiate the model class and then load the checkpoint data. However, I don't know what model class this belongs to, and the documents don't say. Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried unpickling the `best_model.pt` file and checking its attributes?

Comment: See https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html